# How to process ngxs observable before component template is executed

Tags: angular, observable, ngxs

I have an angular 10 project using the  `@ngxs/store` node.js package v3.6.2, and I am attempting to make state subscriptions in a service class, process the results immediately in-service, then pass the result to a component.

My service class which currently doesn't work:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Store } from '@ngxs/store';
import { Models } from './models/document.model';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { async } from 'rxjs/internal/scheduler/async';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProjectService {
    documents$: Observable<Models.Document[]>;
    activeDocumentTitle$: Observable<string>;
    activeDocument: Models.Document;
    activeDocumentTitle: string;

    constructor(private store: Store) {
        this.activeDocumentTitle$ = this.store.select(state => state.meta.activeDocumentTitle);
        this.documents$ = this.store.select(state => state.project.documents);
    }

    getActiveDocument(): Models.Document {
        (this.documents$ | async).filter(
            document => document.title === (this.activeDocumentTitle$ | async))[0];
        return this.activeDocument;
    }
}
```

**What I want to do**: I want to perform a select on an array of objects and at a later time filter this array down to an object that has a property matching the supplied string; finally, I want to pass the first element of this filtered array to a component. My base question is 'can this be achieved?'.

I've googled this to death and have studied the official documentation thoroughly ([ngxs documentation](https://www.ngxs.io/concepts/select)) and it seems that the only way you can get the actual data selected by the observable is in a component template as follows:

```
{{ observableVar | async }}
```

Is this really the only way you can interact with observables with ngxs - you can't mess with the data at all before jumping to the html template?

Comment: This more of an RxJS question. In Angular `| async` can only be used within the template. When you want subscribe to the RxJS-Observable before that you can use `this.document$.subscribe()`.
But then you also have to be aware of the subscription handling in your component. By using `| async` in the template this is done automatically. So it is a recommended best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From an NGXS view the use of a service class here is redundant - NGXS store holds the state so you don't need a service class to also hold state (like activeDocument or activeDocumentTitle).

Instead define a `Selector` that will allow you to combine those two states and map the result to the format you need.  E.g. inferring a little from your example code, in `ProjectsState` define a selector like:

```
@Selector([ProjectsState, MetaState])
static activeDocument(projectsState: ProjectStateModel, metaState: MetaStateModel) {

   if (!metaState.activeDocumentTitle) {
      return null;
   }
   return projectsState.project.documents.find(d => d.title === metaState.activeDocumentTitle);

}
```

Then in your component, access that selector

`@Selector(ProjectsState.activeDocument) activeDocument$: Observable<Document>;`

And then access it in the component template using `activeDocument$ | async`

This is preferable than having to manually subscribe (and unsubscribe) in the component.

See more options in [Joining Selector](https://www.ngxs.io/concepts/select#joining-selectors) and [Meta Selector](https://www.ngxs.io/concepts/select#meta-selectors) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This question was answered in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63085744/how-to-process-ngxs-observable-before-component-template-is-executed#comment111557770_63085744). the `subscribe()` method was exactly what I was after.